# VLOOKUP formula working in one sheet but not the other

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two identical sheets, and the array/vlookup formula is working in one, but not the other. I've tried to make sure both are formatted exactly the same, but it's just not working. Can anyone tell me why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two sheets are not, in fact, identical. `QUERY` can only return one kind of information per column, not a mix; and the type returned will be the one that occurs the most. So your "WORKS" formula works because you have more numbers than text in Column E; but the "doesn't work" sheet does not work because it has many more instances of the string "done" in Column E, so only the string type is being returned.

Beyond that, your two formulas actually aren't the same. For instance, your first formula asks for a return of null-string where null-string is found in `B3:B`, while your second formula replaces those with spaces.

In order to be sure you are only returning numerical content in the `QUERY` regardless of inclusions of strings in Column E, you'll need to pre-process the information to `FILTER` in only the rows where Column E contains a number. However, pre-processing creates new virtual arrays in memory, and so direct column-letter references will need to be exchanged for `Colx` notation.

Delete the `A3` formula in the "doesn't work" sheet and try replacing it with this one:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(B3:B="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3:B,QUERY(FILTER(B3:E,ISNUMBER(E3:E)),"Select Col1, Min(Col4) WHERE Col4<30 GROUP BY Col1"),2,FALSE))))`

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize the mix of data would make a difference! It all makes sense now. Thank you so much, and thank you for the formula! I've finally got my thing to work now. You're awesome! - ps. apologies for that. I copied the data over as it was, and I didn't realize there were straggler "done"s at the end that somehow stayed. My fault for not double checking!

Comment: Glad I could help clarify that for you. If you would, please take a moment to click the checkmark beside the above post to mark it as "Best Answer." This allows the contributor community to see from the main dashboard page which posts have already been resolved; and it allows future site visitors to most quickly find relevant answers to their own similar issues. Thanks.